# Gradient not working in IE 10/11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10, gradient, internet-explorer-11

here my CSS to get the gradient working in any browser, inlcuding IE up to version 9 (IE9):

```
.wrapper { 
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top , #0f1925, #000) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;                                      
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top , #0f1925, #000) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; 
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top , #0f1925, #000) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; 
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr='#0f1925', endColorStr='#000', GradientType=0); 
}
```

It won't work for IE 10/11 though.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've had some issues with IE and gradients too. I've used this website which helped alot: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internet Explorer 10+ uses the [standard syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj152126%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #000, #FFF);
```

Answer (score 1):

DX filters are no longer [supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ie/hh801215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for IE 10+ in standard mode. Use `linear-gradient`.