# Internet Explorer - IE, Linear Gradient (linear-gradient)

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Good day.

I am having an issue getting linear-gradient to work when I test it on IE 11. In every other browser I have tested including Chrome, FireFox, Edge, etc. everything works as expected but IE does not render things correctly.

During my search for answers I reviewed multiple stack overflow posts - [post one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522101/linear-gradient-not-working-in-ie-11) and [post two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843293/gradient-not-working-in-ie-10-11). Although those posts and others provide some insight, based on my review, my CSS should work - see below.

```
CSS{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 50%;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 
  0, 0, 0.6) 50%), to(transparent));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 50%, 
  transparent);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 50%, 
  transparent);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 50%, 
  transparent);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 50%, 
  transparent);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-
}
```

Of the CSS above, I assume I will need to adjust something related to the -ms-linear-gradient line. I have also included an image for review as well; the top image is what I want things to look like in IE.

If anyone can provide any additional perspective or insight it would be appreciated.

[image: example-image]

Comment: A quick search lead me to this. You may want to review it as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093708/diagonal-gradient-in-ie

Comment: You also have what might be a typo. "z-". If that is supposed to be a z-index, I would fix it. If it's extra code, I would just get rid of it.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)